# How to get the corresponding blob File from a SafeUrl object, in Angular4 ?

Tags: javascript, angular, cropper

I'm working on a **Angular4** project where I'm using this library https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper for a image cropper dialog. 
The library has an `imageFileChanged` attribute which can be used to set the file you want to crop. The passed value should be a `File` type but in my code I have only a `SafeUrl` value kept in a store service. 
How should I handle this `SafeUrl` object to get the right file and pass it to the imageCropper?

Thank you!